# Does Stack Overflow keep evolving—or has it evolved—due to user opinions?

Tags: discussion, meta

I came across an [Anti-Stack Overflow post](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d). It has many other negative user experiences mentioned in the "Related" section at the bottom of the page.

So, does Stack Overflow care about those opinions and try to take some measures so there are no (or minimal) such blog posts on popular platforms?

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late

Comment: I would say yes and that snowflakes like the one who wrote that blog post is in a minority. They pop up on meta regularly and the votes send a clear message about who is in the majority. With a user base this large it goes without saying that you can't please everybody and that leads to posts like the one you found.

Comment: I must say that most of the points raised in that post (rant) are no longer valid. SO has changed a lot since that was written.

Comment: Thanks @ivarni @Cerbrus for your explanation and with `Barth's` answer everything seems to be taken positively and constructively

Comment: Does that blog post keep evolving due to user opinions? In response to changes made to Stack Overflow since it was published? Or even to reveal the misconceptions or outright fabrications that underlain many of its premises? Unfortunately, no. Yet we keep getting linked to it as if we'd never seen it before. It is puzzling to me. If you don't like the site or its rules, no one is forcing you to participate.

Comment: @CodyGray i know that I am not forced, it was just a question I had, So I asked it. Thanks for your nice explanation. I think people write stuff like that when they interact with some arrogant users on SO. Lets hope *these users* evolve in positive manner regarding their arrogance to help SO and its users.

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for emphasis. Use **bold** or *italics*, instead. Code formatting is only for code.

Comment: `Code formatting is only for code.` Well, almost.

Comment: *Exclusively*, @Pekka. It isn't for quotations, either. Use quotation marks and/or italics.

Comment: [Be-Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) is great SO help center link for answering and commenting that some `not-so-nice` users _must_ go through to help SO and its users.

Comment: @rdj7: we don't tolerate outright arrogance here. If you see users act in an arrogant manner violating our [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy, flag that and leave it to the moderators to handle. But don't conflate arrogance with insisting on quality standards, which is what the author of that post seems to do.

Comment: @Martijn I understand and I have flagged what seemed arrogant. Also I will keep in mind what you have suggested regarding quality standards. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, Stack Overflow cares about user opinion. Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange are a proof of that. Check the number of times that a feature request has been implemented... or declined with an explanation. You don't get that kind of response in many places. The site has evolved a lot due to the feature requests on MSO and MSE.

As for that post you linked... there's more like that one. Most of these are just rants. People both love and hate Stack Overflow at the same time. On the one hand, it is a great resource, on the other hand, it is moderated very sternly. But in the end, these are two sides of the same coin: it is a great resource *because* it is moderated so sternly. The harsh moderation is simply the price that we all pay.

Comment: through first half of your answer i got how SO has evolved and most importantly through second one I understood that we need to be open towards both sides of this great resource. Thanks !!! Hoping to take all criticism positively and constructively now on :)